# Object reference still returning null even with IsNullOrWhiteSpace?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object

I read up on the below thread and I couldn't find anything in regards to the issue I'm having.
[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
My error is occurring on the View after attempting to load the page for the very first time. When I read through that page it looked to all be referencing the controller I've backtracked and they are all referencing something, so I'm not exactly sure what else I can do...

[image]

I am getting this error at

```
@foreach (string pg in Model.Paygroups)
```

in my view. I'm a little confused because I have Paygroups specified, and in my controller, I am sending the list to the model. I've tried messing with it for a couple of hours, but I'm not seeing where I'm not referencing the object. Any help is appreciated.

Controller

```
    public class UpdateFilesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(string Paygroup)
        {

            var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles"), "paygroup.txt");
            List<string> paygroupsList = new List<string> { System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullpath) };
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                paygroupsList.Add(Paygroup);
                ViewBag.Message($"{Paygroup} succesfully added");
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Paygroup))
            {
                UploadFiles model = new UploadFiles
                {
                    Paygroups = paygroupsList
                };
                return View(model);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
    public class UploadFiles
    {
        public List<string> Paygroups { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a paygroup.")]
        public string PayGroup { get; set; }

    }
```

View

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.UploadFiles
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Paygroup Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Update Paygroup</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "UpdateFiles", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PayGroup, new {@class = "control-label"})
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PayGroup, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PayGroup)}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PayGroup, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
}
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("@ViewBag.Message");
        </script>
    }
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Paygroups</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach (string pg in Model.Paygroups)
        {
            <td>@pg</td>
        }
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is `Model` null?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a [canonical answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose), not for your exact problem, but the basic idea of "something somewhere is `null`; use the debugger to find it."  If not `Model` then is the `Model.Paygroups` collection itself `null`?  Even if not, the fact that it's the responsibility of the user of the `UploadFiles` class to create the `List<>` for `Paygroups` - rather than `UploadFiles` creating a `get`-only `List<>` itself - seems error-prone.

Comment: That...actually makes sense. I was creating the list in the post with the expectation that it would generate the list on load, but I was having a brain fluff forgetting post happens after the user hits the button... This resolved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: In your code, `Paygroup` is just a string passed to the method by you which is then tested with `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.  The `Paygroups` must be a collection of strings since that is what you assign to it - which means it is something altogether different and perhaps even unrelated to `Paygroup`.   Testing a string will not prevent a collection from being null.  The dupe applies

Answer (score 0):

After taking what Bacon said into consideration I resolved my issue by simply moving my list and referencing my model into my GET edit()

```
public class UpdateFilesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles"), "paygroup.txt");
        List<string> paygroupsList = new List<string> { System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullpath) };
        UploadFiles model = new UploadFiles
        {
            Paygroups = paygroupsList
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(string Paygroup)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles"), "paygroup.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullpath, Paygroup);
            ViewBag.Message = ($"{Paygroup} succesfully added");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "UpdateFiles");
    }
}
```